# Can we use '+' as a ID of a element in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, web

I was working on calculator. in that website i have decided to give each buttons ID with respect to their value (eg 1) so in + button i gave ID of '+'. In JS it was working fine if i use

```
document.getElementById("+");
```

but if i use

```
document.querySelector("#+");
```

or

```
$("#+");
```

it wont work and gives this error "Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '#+' is not a valid selector"

Can anyone explain why this is happening
Thanks

Comment: Can you?  Yes (with escaping).   Should you?  No - call it `id="plus"`

Answer (score 2):

> Can anyone explain why this is happening

Basically: Selector syntax has rules.

---

See the [CSS specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#id-selectors):

> An ID selector contains a "number sign" (U+0023, #) immediately followed by the ID value, which must be an CSS identifiers.

Which links to:

> In CSS, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in selectors) can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646 characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore (_); they cannot start with a digit, two hyphens, or a hyphen followed by a digit.

So `+` isn't allowed.

> Identifiers can also contain escaped characters and any ISO 10646 character as a numeric code (see next item). For instance, the identifier "B&W?" may be written as "B&W?" or "B\26 W\3F".

---

So you need to escape it (remembering that `\` is a special character in JavaScript string literals and needs escaping there too).

```js
document.querySelector("#\\+").textContent = "Hello, world";
```

```html
<div id="+"></div>
```

---

… or not use weird ID values.